# can an http client lie about a request's content-length?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

specifically, i'm talking about from the point of view of a node.js server. it's hard to test this in node.js because `http.client` validates `content-length`.

can a client lie about a body's content-length, at least at the point it reaches `http.createServer().on('request')`?

- Can a client send a body that is larger than `content-length`? I don't think this is possible as it is most likely checked at the parser level, but i want proof.
- Can a client send a body that is smaller than `content-length`? I think this may be true.

i'm worried about malicious users that may not use a well-behaved http client.

Comment: yes. `http.client` validates it so it never even reaches the server. i don't know how non-node.js clients work.

Comment: See also: [HTTP: Can I trust 'Content-Length' request header value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. You could simply open a TCP socket connection to whatever IP/port a web server is running on and write anything you'd like there. Of course well-behaved clients don't do this, but there's nothing stopping a client from doing so.

However, this tends to be the problem of whatever HTTP stack you're using on the server, in this case Node. It needs to 1) not blindly read in (huge) content-length bytes as that could crash the server miserably and 2) make sure (for reasonable-sized requests) that the client isn't lying.

In the case of node, it's visible right about here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/http_parser/http_parser.c#L1471

Just try it and see ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it depends
of course you can send a wring content length, the question is what does the client do with it.
there are script or server clients that may attempt to download your content and get completely messed up.
most browsers seem to have some error tolerant behaviour implemented however there are many differenet implementations.
i remember having a old ie keeping the socket open never closing it. this ended up in a never ending page load.
some netscape browser seem to be totally dependent on the right content length.
a good idea is to leave content-legths away. this should work on every browser.